# Stacked barchart with confidence intervalin Python

Tags: python, bar-chart, data-visualization, confidence-interval

I'm new on Python and I have a problem like this. 
I have to represent the results of a survey, with the following values: Positive or Negative.
However, I acted on a sample, so I have to represent also the confidence interval of the results.
My idea is to represent a stacked barchart (in percentage, where clearly the entire bar is the 100%) divided in Positive and Negative, but with a sort of representation of the confidence. Is there someone with a valid code?

Comment: Providing a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help...
Please give at least a sample of your input data and a result to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

For data visualisation using Python I would suggest using the [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) library.

For your barchart suggestion maybe have a look at the following barchart example taken from the matplotlib website.

[Barchart Example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-api-barchart-py)

As a suggestion, if you are looking at showing a comparison of total Positive and Negative values perhaps you should consider using a pie chart. See the following example taken from the matplotlib website again.

[Basic Pie Chart Example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-pie-features-py)